# Feature selection using bigram

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection

I have rows of product description data,from which I need to extract the features.I am trying to convert the rows to bigrams and then I am extracting the features 
using the code below:

```
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(description) 
scored = finder.score_ngrams(bgm.likelihood_ratio)
```

After executing the above code, all the rows in description gets concatenated and following bigrams are formed.

**For Example:**

for description

```
**Description**
    running cleaning observed cooling cleaned
    rectangu minuteria fplease rectanglur
```

I am getting bigram output like:

```
(runnin,cleaning),(cleaning, observed),(observed ,cooling),(cooling ,cleaned),(cleaned,rectangu),(rectangu, minuteria),(minuteria ,fplease), (,fplease rectanglur )
```

but my required output is:

```
(runnin,cleaning),(cleaning, observed),(observed ,cooling),(cooling ,cleaned),(rectangu, minuteria),(minuteria ,fplease), (,fplease rectanglur )
```

the difference is bigram **(cleaned,rectangu)** are formed by with the last word of the first row and the first word of the next row and so on.

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: Is your `description` a string where each row is separated by a `\n`?

Comment: Yes the description is in the form of string but they are not separated by \n@Scratch'N'Purr

Comment: If the lines aren't separated by a `\n`, then it's a `\r`? I'm trying to understand how it would be two rows if there's no newline sequence. Otherwise, it would be hard to build your custom bigram generator without that distinction.